# Access VBA type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm creating a database for a local rental company.  What I'm trying to do right now is create some code that can be periodically run to add bills to the database.

I have two tables I'm referencing here, the first is tblRental which is a  table of rental units which includes rentalID's as a primary key, rental status, and the monthly rent, which is different on each unit.  The other is tblTransaction which among other things includes the rentalID as a foreign key in a 1 to many relationship, and the amount for each bill which is named UnitRate.  In the database rentalID and UnitRate are both set to numbers.

My code right now is

```
Dim maxRentalID As Integer

Dim db As Database
Dim rentID As DAO.Recordset
Dim unit As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
maxRentalID = Combo4.Value

For i = 1 To maxRentalID
    Set rentID = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblRental.RentalID, tblRental.Status FROM tblRental WHERE (((tblRental.Status)='3') AND ((tblRental.RentalID)=" & i & "));")
    Set unit = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblRental.Rentalcharge FROM tblRental WHERE (((tblRental.RentalID)=" & i & "));")
    If rentID Is Not Null Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblTransction ([RentalID], [UnitRate]) VALUES (" & rentID, unit & ");"
    End If
Next
```

maxRentalID is obtained from a form which determines the ID of the last record so that the for loop will go through until the end.

Right now I get a type mismatch error and it tells me the problem is with rentID in the DoCmd.RunSQL line.

I'm trying to make the loop run a query, and if it's a valid result (status=3 on a RentalID that exists), insert a new record into tblTransaction with that RentalID and corresponding billing rate.

Based on what the debugger says I assume that what's happening is the SQL isn't being evaluated into a statement with the query value being assigned to the variable and it's trying to put the statement into a number field which doesn't work.  I'm not sure how to make it evaluate properly however.  I've tried using OpenRecordSet for that but it doesn't work.

Comment: **1)** `rentID` and `unit` are _recordsets_, but not values. **2)** replace `If rentID Is Not Null Then` with `If Not rentID.EOF Then` **3)** `VALUES (" & rentID, unit & ");"`-->`VALUES (" & rentID.Fileds("RentalID"), unit.Fileds("Rentalcharge") & ");"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it without loop and opening recordsets:

```
Dim maxRentalID As Integer
maxRentalID = Combo4.Value

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tblTransction] ([RentalID], [UnitRate]) " & _ 
                "SELECT [tblRental].[RentalID], [tblRental].[Rentalcharge] " & _ 
                "FROM [tblRental] " & _ 
                "WHERE [tblRental].[Status]='3' AND " & _ 
                      "[tblRental].[RentalID] BETWEEN 1 AND " & maxRentalID
```